# Issue accessing query parameter "@type" in API Manager sequence

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I'm encountering an issue while trying to access the query parameter "@type" from my API Manager sequence file. I have attempted to use the following code:

```
<property name="type" expression="$url:@type"/>
```

However, it does not seem to work as expected. The value of the "@type" query parameter is not being retrieved correctly.

Could someone kindly guide me on how to access the query parameter "@type" correctly within an API Manager sequence file?